# How to the get php variable every time I click the button and then use it for query?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I`am trying to get the $row['username'] every time I click on the button, for me to use it in the query . But only the first array is displayed.
I want to use jquery but I have small knowledge on it.

```
<?php
  $query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM account WHERE acc = 'agency'");
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
  {
    echo $row['username'];
  ?>
    <button data-target="#select" data-toggle="modal">Select</button>
<?php } ?>


  <div class="modal" id="select">
  <?php
    $query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM sample WHERE username = ".$row['username']."");

  ?>
```

Comment: You can put the username on the button as a data field, similar to how you are doing the target and the toggle as data attributes.  Also put a class on the button.  Then you can use jQuery to bind a click handler to the button, finding them by the class, and then you can get the data attribute off of the button.

Comment: You need to go and do some tutorials on how PHP and JavaScript work. `$row` isn't defined outside of your while loop so you can't use it in your second query like that. You should also read up on the difference between server side and client side languages. PHP is server side, all of it has executed before being sent to the clients browser. JavaScript doesn't execute until the browser has finished loading the content sent by the server.

Comment: @Taplar Like this? <button id="select" data-username="<?php echo $row['username']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#select">Select</button>

Comment: @HarlyJohn yep, that would add it as a data attribute.  Then all you need is your javascript to bind a click event handler on it.

Comment: @Taplar: What should I do in jquery?

Comment: @Taplar: Could you please do a code in jquery. I have small knowledge on it I`m sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
<button id="select"
        class="selectUser"
        data-username="<?php echo $row['username']; ?>"
        data-toggle="modal"
        data-target="#select">Select</button>
```

I took the html you put in your comment, and added a class to it.  Now all you need to do is create your javascript binding for it.

```
//find all the buttons with the selectUser class and bind a click handler to them
$('.selectUser').on('click', function(e){
    //turn the element into a jQuery object so we can use jQuery methods
    var $selectUser = $(this);
    //log the username data attribute from the button
    console.log($selectUser.data('username'));

    //you could also get the attribute without jQuery
    console.log(this.getAttribute('data-username'));
});
```

Comment: the $row['username'] in my query still sets the first array.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying.  If you are asking a question related to what your php query is returning, then you are asking about two different things; the php query and how to make the javascript alert the user.  If that is the case then this question is too broad and you need to break the question up into smaller pieces.

Comment: I mean, if I click the button that has the current array. I want to use that array and then use it as the condition in my query for example SELECT * FROM sample WHERE username = ".$row['username']."

Comment: Oh, you can't do that.  As stated in the comments, PHP runs on the server before generating the page that is returned to the client.  It is then on the client that the javascript runs.  And javascript cannot directly invoke php.  They operate on different machines.  You have to perform a web request from the client to the server to execute more php.